# How can I refactor my java code with multiple if conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, refactoring

We have a java code with multiple if conditions(actual code has more than 100 if conditions) to call appropriate methods depending upon the operation name. How can this be refactored in more efficient way?

```
  if ("Customer".equals(header.getString(OPERATION))) 
    CustomerRequest searchRequest = gson.fromJson(paylaod, CustomerRequest.class);
    response = viewCustomerServiceEndpoint.viewCustomer(searchRequest, pool);
  }
  if ("ProfileUpdate".equals(header.getString(OPERATION))) {
    ProfileUpdateRequest searchRequest = gson.fromJson(paylaod, ProfileUpdateRequest.class);
    response = saProfileUpdateEndPoint.saProfileUpdate(searchRequest, pool);
  }
```

Comment: define `enum` with all possible options and use `switch`

Comment: Looks like a use case for the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). 1) you always check if the `OPERATION`-header is equal to something 2) then you convert the payload to a class 3) you pass the request to another class 4) you assign the response. If you always have these 4 steps, then you can make this whole thing generic, though the code stays probably the same if not more. It is just not all in a single if-else chain